# when write Arabic in lyx and add some words in English-The letters in English are inverse

Tags: lyx, arabic, lyx-layouts

I type in Arabic but when I add English words in the same line after Arabic word i notice the English letters are inverses. in the following picture I type two Arabic words from right to left and then I write "hero man"

[image]

hero man.

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language arabic_arabi
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "Simplified Arabic"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "Simplified Arabic"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style french
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
السلام عليكم (hero man) 
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Tex.SX. It's hard for us to recreate the problem and help you if we don't know exactly what's in your file's preamble and definitions. You can add a Minimal Working Example (MWE) in LyX: just open the file in notepad and paste its content in your question

Comment: Do you have Rgiht to Left support checked in Tools → Preferences → Language Settings ?

Comment: yes, there is two options , logical and visual . I choose logical option. thanks a lot for help

Comment: Thanks for the minimal example. I can reproduce the issue now. I think you can get things as you want if you select "hero man" and to to Edit > Text Style > Customize and for the language choose "English". After you do this, the text is interpreted by LyX as English and set Left-to-Right. Does that do what you want?

Comment: thank you very much. This method was successful but needs to be repeated every time I write a new English word or a new English sentence.

Comment: +1: Please consider accepting the provided answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You must select "hero man" and to to Edit > Text Style > Customize and for the language choose "English". After you do this, the text is interpreted by LyX as English and set Left-to-Right. This is not quite as cumbersome when you do it the next time: When there are multiple languages in a document, you can go to Edit > Language.

From what I understand, you would prefer to have the language switch automatically when you switch your keyboard. This is a desired feature that is documented at https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/6450.